# Failed to call stored procedure from Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Power BI desktop

```
USE [Adventure]

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_powerbi]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But I get the following error:

> Details: "Microsoft SQL: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_powerbi', database 'Adventure', schema 'dbo'."

It is strange to me because I had already been able to use a procedure stored in another report and I did not get this error. Do I have to do some configuration in Power BI?

Where can I check the permissions that Power BI mentions? Or where can I check the permissions in Power BI or SQL Server?

Comment: The error tells you everything you need; the SQL user that Power BI is using doesn't have permission to execute that procedure. That fact that some other procedure can be executed is irrelevant. A quick google will show you how to grant permissions to execute a SP if you don't have a DBA to do it for you.

Comment: Hey @emm,
Did it resolve your  error?

Comment: @Nandan 
Remove the connections that I had to sql server, and I called the store procedure again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the below command in the SQL database which is your source:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [< User >];
```

This is not a PowerBI issue but access issue in the database side.